# DatabaseError unable to open database file

Tags: database, django, apache, permissions

My sqlite db file is this: `unable to open database file` i chowned all folders until my dbfile to root. but i am still getting this error. but i remember that while creating my django project on server, i created a superuser, and now if i do `ls -l` i see that the user is that superuser. how is it possible to tell apache that this superuser should have that right to write/read the db file? or how to solve the problem, i am not apache/linux guru..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Execute `chown www-data:www-data directory` on the directory you want apache to be able to write to.

Comment: yeah but it is saying: invalid group www-data. do i have to create it first?

Comment: see my last comment above, but still unable to open database file.

Comment: `cat /etc/group | grep www-data` type this to see whether group exists.

Comment: oh yeah, the group exists. is it a group or a user? because it is on users list.

Comment: it is a group. try this in your project root directory . `sudo chown -Rf www-data *`

Comment: which tool r u using to open database file?

Comment: i am in shell now thru puTTy on server. i open database file with 'vi dbfile', but it was not interesting for me till now, first i need to get it writable and readable. or is it also important issue in permissions ?

Comment: now i deleted and syncdb again, the db file is fresh now, but the same error, actually deleting and creating again doesnot help now, i know..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11910/discussion-between-priyank-patel-and-doniyor)

Comment: See this link [sqllite in production](http://www.pantz.org/software/sqlite/unabletoopendbsqliteerror.html)

Comment: hey, Priyank, problem solved, many thanks for help. great people in stackoverflow!. 'chown www-data. .' then 'chmod 777 dbfile'  i dont know whether i did this earlier, but anyway, i learnt new things. lol

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just leave the file as owned by the super user and just change the group so that apache can read/write it as well.

Change the group for the sqlite file and the containing directory. Try this:

```
cd <directory with sqlite file>
sudo chgrp www-data . <sqlitefile>
```

Comment: it says, invalid group www-data. :(. do i have to create it first?

Comment: okay i did, it was not chgrp but chown, because www-data is not a group, right? but still it is saying, unable to open database file..

Answer (score 0):

You can find write group and  www user and change  permissions.
Say: cat /etc/passwd  - for find right user, It may be apache or http or www.
And say to terminal: cat /etc/group -for find right group.
In my system group=apache, user = apache.